# How can I capture packets belonging to a certain process

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, sniffing

I need to capture packets belonging to a program or process. I know Winshark, but it just displays network traffic in a mess (in my view).

If one wants to get the packets of a given process, you must find the PID first, then set a filter and so on.

Is there any way to gather the connection information and transmission of data packets by process or process tree with a more friendly interface?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any software gather the connection information and transmission of data packets by process or process tree with friendly interface?

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)?